# Finding new line in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment I have a file that lists different elements and either gives them a letter or a number, and what I want to do is move the elements with a letter slightly to the right so it can easily be seen that is a different type of element from the ones with a letter.

So far I have a code that puts 5 empty spaces at the beginning for elements with a letter, and my issue is that when it is a long text that takes up more than 1 line it cannot recognise that there is more than 1 line and add empty spaces to those.

Additionally, I have a code that recognises when there is a new line but only if enter was used when creating the text for the cell, this does not work for long text where it takes up more than 1 line in the cell and an enter has not been used

Code:

```
Sub Module_1()

For i = 5 To 8

ValueCell = Cells(i, 3).Value
Cells(i, 3).Value = "     " & ValueCell
Cells(i, 3).Replace What:=vbLf, Replacement:=vbLf & "     ", LookAt:=xlPart

Next i
End Sub
```

Example:

This is the items without the code being applied to it
[image: This is the items without the code being applied to it]

These are the items with the code applied to them
[image: These are the items with the code applied to them]

As you can see it works but C5 and C7 as there arent extra lines, it also works for C8 as enter was used to create the text in that cell, but it does not work for C6

I was wondering if there is something like vbLf but for recognising a new line inside the cell when it is a long text, or if there is a way to do this by just adding a tab or something to all of the lines at once

Also, at the moment I do not want to make the cell wider to avoid this issue as in the actual file some really long text will appear where its not possible to make the cell as wide as the text is. I am also not looking to "align" the text, just move it a bit to the right.

Comment: just align left with 1 or more spaces and maybe use wrap text too - which I think you are already are. this will accomplish your goal of visually moving that text to the right.

Comment: Why not just change the indentation instead of adding all those spaces? I think you're reinventing functionality that already exists. Right click > Format Cells > Alignment > Indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop needed. Just set the `.IndentLevel = 1` for this range at once

```
Sub Module_1()
    With Range(Cells(5, 3), Cells(8, 3))
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .WrapText = True
        .IndentLevel = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I applied this to `Range("B5:C8")` and it automatically looks like this:

[image]

---

Alternatively do it without VBA:

Select cells › Right click › Format Cells › Alignment › Indent *(sorry for the german screenshot).*

[image]